# Building Python IoTEdge Module for Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi, azure-iot-edge, azure-container-registry

I am trying to build a Python IoTEdge module for a Raspberry Pi 4 (uses Docker to build image).

I set the target architecture for my IoTEdge solution as `arm32v7`

I don't believe anything is wrong with my `requirements.txt`, but just for reference:

**requirements.txt**

```
azure-iot-device~=2.0.0
opencv-python
numpy
requests
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM arm32v7/python:3.7-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "-u", "./main.py" ]
```

I run the following command:

```
docker build  --rm -f "path/to/Dockerfile" -t dockerTag "path/to/module/project"
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Step 4/7 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 515aac4bdc38
standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

I read [here](https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-images/) that to build to ARM, I have to use `docker buildx` instead. I created a `buildx` container with `--platform linux/arm32`. I switched to using this container, and run:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm32 --rm -f "path/to/Dockerfile" -t dockerTag "path/to/module/project"
```

However, now I get:

```
 => ERROR [4/7] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                                                                                                                        2.2s
------                                                                                                                                                                          
 > [4/5] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt:
#8 0.727 standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
------
Dockerfile.arm32v7:22
--------------------
  20 |     #     libcurl4-openssl-dev
  21 |     
  22 | >>> RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
  23 |     
  24 |     COPY . .
--------------------
error: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
```

My development machine:

- Chip: Intel i7 4510u
- OS: Manjaro KDE

I also tried to build it directly on the Raspberry Pi 4 itself, but alas, it gave me the same errors.
I'm at a loss of what to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try pip install --no-binary

Comment: @Joe unfortunately, it results in the same errors :(

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, it successfully built when I was on a Windows machine, instead of using Manjaro Linux. I still wonder why...